# Product Page without www redirect to home instead of itself

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, htaccess, apache2

If I type mysite.com/myproduct-name or mysite.it/myproduct-name without www it brings me to the respective homepage (I have 2 domains: www.mysite.com and www.mysite.it).

.htaccess part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.it/ [R=301,L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]


SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
```

- In this situation redirect of product is resolved but I can access only to www.mysite.it
- If I uncomment row 3 and 4 I'm not able to access both domains anymore.
- If I remove ! from both conditions I can access to both domains but redirect to www product page doesn't work anymore

**How can set it so that redirect me to the www version of the content (e.g. www.mysite.com/myproduct-name)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `System->Configuration->Web->Url Options` and set the field `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `No`.

Comment: Thank you but, if I set this I can access both homepage version with and without www. I want access ONLY to the www version.

Comment: More specifically, doing this product redirect (mysite.com/myproduct --> www.mysite.com/myproduct) works but now home redirect doesn't (site.com --> site.com).

Comment: @KaMZaTa tou should be able to solve the home page issue with a rewrite rule. At least the rest of the pages work.

Comment: And how? I have different domains and condition rule ^mysite.it$ doesn't seems match. Only match !^mysite.it$ but doing this excludes also other domain.

Answer (score 0):

First line in .htaccess needs to be changed to include www prefix (as there is negation in the condition). Redirect in the second line should include request URL, so it would be like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.it/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.it%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Other non-matching requests you can redirect in similar way to www.mysite.com or www.mysite.it as needed.

Comment: Doing this way generates a loop between www.mysite.com and www.mysite.it

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have corrected the answer assuming both domains are active. The previous reply was for single domain only.

Comment: Doing this way I can access both domains but product page without www lead to homepage and not to itself.