# Magento2: Remove home after base url

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, base-url

How to remove `/home` after  `baseUrl` ?

> www.baseurl.com/home

I want to redirect `www.baseurl.com/home` to `www.baseurl.com` (301)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using htaccess file . In htacess file find:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on`

Then Put the below code in htaccess file

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/home
RewriteRule ^(.*)home$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

or you can do this by

Go to `System->Configuration->Web->Url Options` and set the field `Auto-redirect to Base URL` to `No`.

Please check following links for more reference
[Product Page without www redirect to home instead of itself](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42834/product-page-without-www-redirect-to-home-instead-of-itself)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23129310/magento-redirect-the-url-from-www-domain-com-home-to-base-url-www-domain-com

Comment: This solution will work perfectly, but when we programmatically get the base url it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

First update both the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` URLs in `core_config_data` table to `http://www.baseurl.com/` in your database.

Then clear the cache and remove `generated/` folder

Ensure you have updated your `virtual host settings` according to the new URL.

Once you set the applied the virtual host changes, `restart the apache server`